# How to create a Redact Policy in oracle

Tags: oracle, redaction

I am trying to create a redact policy to hide NIC from Customer table for all users.

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_REDACT.ADD_POLICY (
   object_schema       => 'RETAILX',
   object_name         => 'CUSTOMER',
   column_name         => 'NIC',
   policy_name         => 'REDACT_NIC_POLICY',
   function_type       => DBMS_REDACT.PARTIAL,
   function_parameters => 'MDy1',
expression             => '1=1'
 );
END;
```

Above is my code for the policy creation. However, I am getting an error while creating the policy. Error as below.

ORA-06550: line 7, column 27:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_REDACT' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

What Could be wrong here?

Comment: What is the version of your DBMS?

Comment: May need a grant like: grant execute on sys.dbms_redact to youruser; See https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/data-redaction-12cr1

Comment: @BobbyDurrett I tried grant execute on sys.dbms_redact to retailx; However, It says "table or view does not exist"

Comment: I think you need to login as SYS to do the grant. On Unix/Linux I do sqlplus / as sysdba to login as sys. To check if DBMS_REDACT exists run select * from dba_objects where object_name='DBMS_REDACT';